# How to change terminal's theme?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gnome-terminal, gnome-tweaks

I tried to change default Konsole/Terminal theme, I downloaded one from pling.com, and then i used tweaks to set it

[image: it]

The thing is that my terminal still has the default theme, even after restarting my computer.

[image: default theme]

Also it looks like the theme that I set in the Shell option in tweaks overrided my actual Layan theme. Did i mis-understood what the Shell option in tweaks was ? I just want to change my terminal theme.

Comment: You haven't given OS & release details; but you've tagged numerous GNOME items but mention Konsole (a Qt5/KDE terminal) which has me confused. Which are you trying to theme? and what are you trying to change?  (I wonder if it's just $PS1 or the prompt)

Comment: yes well actually i wanted to theme whatever terminal, whether gnome-shell or konsole( not just the prompt). i thought that this shouldve been done by the shell-theme option in tweaks. But now i understand how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Gnome Shell theme changes shell buttons, colors, panels, etc., and not the actual terminal I believe.

For example: Draculatheme.com has a GTK theme as well as a gnome-terminal

I believe you would need to find out if that theme has a terminal "theme"( for lack of a better word) and set it to that.

I was trying to find a gnome-terminal version that matches the theme but im not able to.

Someone that knows this MUCH more than I do might be able to confirm/deny anything I have said and inform us correctly though.